# windows 7 goes crazy after multiple rdp sessions

Tags: windows-7, rdp

On several different windows 7 machines after using multiple rdp sessions, the local computer begins to act like a function key is locked on.  Windows will start opening and closing windows as I type and only a few of the characters will show up normally.  The solution to get rid of this issue is to depress the windows key and than num lock, to return to normal keyboard operation.  A reboot will also fix the issue.  Does anyone know what causes this and how to prevent it from occurring in the first place?

Comment: Multiple session2 from Win7 to other machines or multiple inbound connections?

Comment: Multiple outbound sessions from the win 7 machine to other workstations and server.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I'll chime in I've had this issue too, although not all the time. The only commonality I can figure out is that every time it happens i have the VIC client up and 3-4 console sessions open. I think it has something to do with the way it captures Keyboard/mouse. Now that being said I haven't seen the issue since I've upgraded my client to vSphere 4 so I could manage some new servers. But I've only been up to vSphere 4 for about 2 months now.

Comment: i've seen it with the VIC client & with vmware workstation, so def vmware related

Comment: I am glad you pointed out the vmware connection.  I have only had this issue on win 7 machines with VIC installed, but I am using vSphere 4 on some of them that exhibit the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too.  something that's quicker then a reboot is locking & then unlocking your local workstation.